# Obj-C Crashes on app launch in main view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

Looking for some debugging help on my project. I removed extra/commented code and must've removed something key to the foundation of the app, as it no longer launches.

Background: the project is the construction of a [a snapchat clone from an education site, team treehouse][1]. The app name is Ribbit and it gets its backend functionality through the use of the Parse SDK.

I've added an exception breakpoint and it seems like there's some error that happens when the viewWillAppear gets called in the InboxTableViewController, which is the main view controller presented to the user on launch.

If anyone can spot the error and give me guidance on how to fix it, I'd be very grateful. As far as I can tell, there's a problem that arises immediately after

```
[query whereKey:@"recipientIDs" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
```

The app was built using Xcode version 6.4 (6E35b)

Project link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1hfu8aguZOFUXVsbGNEQmdnMW8/view?usp=sharing

[http://cl.ly/image/1n2c0G0P1Y1T/  "Link to screenshot of error log, with exception breakpoint"](http://cl.ly/image/1n2c0G0P1Y1T/)

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: What is the full stack?

Comment: [stack trace screenshot w/ exception breakpoint here](http://cl.ly/image/1n2c0G0P1Y1T)

[screenshot without exception breakpoint](http://cl.ly/image/0Q2k192v202N) no real text to the error message: I can see a memory address, and some other messages around *argv that I'm not sure how to interpret

Comment: That exception breakpoint is nice to find the line of the error.  But turn it off for a moment to get a full console log.  Please paste that here.

Comment: @danh here you are:

argc int 1 1
argv char ** 0x7fff5a622290 0x00007fff5a622290
*argv char * "/Users/anthony/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/424E7654-692A-430C-A646-853ED9E6FBE1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/517A64C5-FB26-407B-B436-4AB77985EE7A/Ribbit.app/Ribbit" 0x00007fff5a622538
**argv char '/' '/'

Comment: hey @danh sorry, I hovered over the code and can see this message in the main.m:

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Helpful?

Answer (score 3):

You are crashing on this line:

```
[query whereKey:@"recipientIDs" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
```

The reason for the crash is that `[PFUser currentUser]` returns `nil` in your code.

If you look at the currentUser method the docs say:

```
/*!
 @abstract Gets the currently logged in user from disk and returns an instance of it.

 @returns Returns a `PFUser` that is the currently logged in user. If there is none, returns `nil`.
 */
+ (PF_NULLABLE instancetype)currentUser;
```

So either log in, or don't presume that `[PFUser currentUser]` is valid.

Comment: Unlikely.  currentUser == nil would cause objectId to return nil would pass nil to equalTo:, which might not find any results, but wouldn't crash.  I think we should wait for the OP to paste the error (the exception breakpoint stops before the error is written to console).

Comment: @danh Look at the stack trace. The `equalTo:` method is throwing an assertion probably because `nil` is being passed in.

Comment: @rmaddy - yeah, I see now.  would have expected parse sdk to treat nil operands more forgivingly, like `whereKeyDoesNotExist`.  My bad.  Edited so I could reverse my down vote.

Comment: @danh hey danh, very helpful, but there is a check:


`if (currentUser) {
`NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);
`} else {
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
`    }

so I'm expecting the app to prompt me to log in at sign-in, not crash? is this helpful?

PS - sorry, I can't seem to the get the code formatting to work

Comment: Hmm. That error content is still pretty opaque. And I think you're saying there's logic guarding against a nil user. If there was no segue with that identifier in IB (outbound from the vc referred to by self) then that would cause a crash. Or if any of the outlets on the destination vc are undefined, that would also do it.

Comment: @danh i commented out the line and boom, problem solved. removed the comment (put the code back into play) and, well this is quite strange - the error seems to have resolved itself? which makes me think there was some funk coming from Parse on `[query whereKey:@"recipientIDs" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];` line. query is: `PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];` so, i don't know if i was to blame, or i fixed it, or parse was to blame and/or parse fixed it.. so confused, but you've been so helpful. thank you so much

Comment: Glad it's better now.

Comment: one last follow up @danh this crashlytics reports highlights the problem as an issue with the Parse SDK: http://crashes.to/s/6c6e9bd4be2   am i interpreting that correctly?

Comment: Yes.  That's consistent with the point @DShaw makes here.  I was surprised and disappointed to discover that `nil` is an invalid operand to `equalTo:`.  The disappearance of the problem could be attributable to a currentUser being persisted on the machine.  If so, a fresh install would crash again.  The take away is, defend the query with a condition that first checks whether you have a user to query with.